# When sending an array from client to server, how can I access each array index in the server? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I am sending an array to my server using ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/sendToDb",
            type: "POST",
            data: {myArray: top200}
        });
```

I can log out the array using req.body in my Post.

```
app.post('/sendToDb', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){

  console.log(req.body);

});
```

Using req.body, how can I log out an individual index of the array in my server? (Go easy on me. I'm a fairly new coder).

Comment: what do you mean by individual index?

Comment: `req.body['myArray'][index]`?

Comment: I think you mean how to access an specific element from the array through an index.

Comment: The duplicate question is asking about non-Ajax, but from the server side there is no difference, and it is the server side that you are having problems with.